# Installing HAXM "Virtualization Technology is not turned on" error

Tags: android, android-virtual-device, haxm

I'm having an issue installing HAXM. It insists on giving me the "VT is not turned on error" even though I have performed all the following steps -

1. VT is enabled on BIOS
2. Avast -> settings -> troubleshooting -> "Enable hardware-assisted virtualization" is on.
3. Hyper-V is disabled (I already ran "bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off")
4. NX is set to AlwaysOn (I already ran "bcdedit /set nx AlwaysOn")

Any idea what do I do next? I'm still getting the same error whenever trying to install.

Comment: do you have intel or amd processor?

Comment: Enable hardware-assisted virtualization in Avast should be off (not on). Disable, rebootand try again

Comment: @Cookienator Is it working now?

Comment: @GuilhermeP Yes, it is! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following setting must be off. Not on.

> Avast -> settings -> troubleshooting -> "Enable hardware-assisted
>   virtualization"

Disable it, reboot and try again.